# PHP Extract Relative Links from Text

Tags: php, regex, dom

I am trying to extract ALL links from an html page including relative links. I am using regex to get all urls - that is easy - but I want to find relative links too. So I want to be able to find:

```
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Some Link</a>
```

and I also want to be able to find

```
    <a href="somepage.php">Some Other Link</a>
```

I need to do this as quickly as possible using as little memory as possible so I am trying to avoid using DOM stuff and the like. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So, you could just look for `href` and `src` attributes?  Do you need it to get _all_ links, or just the links in attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just trying something like this. Could it be enough?

```
$a = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Some Link</a>';
$p = '/href=\"(?<href>.*?)\">(?<content>.*?)</';
preg_match_all($p, $a, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

and

```
$b = '<a href="somepage.php">Some Other Link</a>';
preg_match_all($p, $b, $m2);
var_dump($m2);
```

If you don't need reference `<href>` that let you access the data like `$m['href']` you can take off so the pattern become

`$p = '/href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</';`

Comment: Ha yep sorry, kind of new to stack!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
\<a.*?(?:href=['"](.*)?['"]|\>)
```

Comment: euhm there is a big difference between character classes `[]` and capturing groups `()` ...

Comment: @HamZa I basically use `[]` for `or`s because I believe `()`s consume more memory by saving the matches `:/` It works either ways tho

Comment: Simply put, `[ab]` will either match an `a` or a `b`. It's the same as `(a|b)`, well `(a|b)` adds it to a capturing group. You could use a non-capturing group `(?:a|b)`. But `[a|b]` means `match an a or a b or a literal |`.

Comment: @HamZa That was a good note. It doesn't work that well with `[href|>]` though. Might as well keep the `|` there, right?

Comment: A character class is totally different from a group (capturing or not). A character class is like a bag where you put single possible characters in any order (a kind of collection). `[href]` is the same than `[refh]`, `[efhr]`, `[fhre]`, `[hfer]`, `[freh]` und so weiter. thus this part of your pattern `[href=['"]` is seen as a character class that can be exactly replaced with `[[r'e="hf]` or any permutation you want. Now, as HamZa explained you, if you want to have the choice between several substrings, you must use enclose these substring inside `(?:..)` and separate each with a `|`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Note taken. Thanks!